# NextJS authentication in server action/fetching

Tags: next.js

I am trying to understand the NextJs using App Routing and how it would work with authentication. Most example I found and even in the docs, they all use the [old routing mode](https://%20%20https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/authenticating#other-providers)

Doing API route for client, and check authentication is pretty straightforward.

- you create api folder with some routes.
- you add your `authentication` checking in the route
- then you call what you need

for example

```
export const PUT = async (req: Request) => {
  const { error, user } = await isAuthenticated(req);
  if (!user) {
    return error;
  }
  return createPlace(req, user);
};
```

`isAuthenticated` doing like

```
const tokenId = headers().get('Authorization')?.replace('Bearer ', '')
...
```

Now in the case I do some Server Component

In the DOC they say, rather than doing this

```
export default async function Page() {
  let res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/data');
  let data = await res.json();
  return <h1>{JSON.stringify(data)}</h1>;
}
```

They recommend querying directly the server since all is run in the server.

```
export default async function Page() {
  // call your async function directly
  let data = await getData(); // { data: 'Next.js' }
  // ...
}
```

But does this mean that all the API call I access like this should not require any authentication? Because if I just call a method directly from the SSR component, I will never have any Authorization token set. Also, cookies are not always available anymore, so this is not a solution.

Comment: In order to implement user auth, this is the best and easy solution to integrate: https://next-auth.js.org/

Comment: Hi, I am already using firebase auth for my authentication

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

There are two scenarios for Next.js authentication:

1. If your data API is unprotected (users should not be able to access it directly) or if you intend to process all backend data directly in Next.js. You need to verify that the credentials carried in the user's cookies are valid before fetching the data.
2. If your backend API is protected. You only need to restrict user permissions in the backend API. In this case, all Next.js needs to do is wrap and forward cookies to the backend API.

> I am already using firebase auth for my authentication.

You need to **manually** use cookies whenever authentication is outside the scope of Next.js server.

---

#### Original answer

> In the DOC they say, rather than doing this ...
> They recommend querying directly the server since all is run in the server.

Yes, but `getData()` calls `fetch()` directly so what you provided is identical. What they mean is just `fetch()` directly without `route handlers` (the `/app/api` folder)

> cookies are not always available anymore.

Why? Cookies should always be available on the server. And that's the right way to handle external authentication.

## How to get client credentials?

When the user sends a request, all headers (including cookies) are sent together to the server.
In this case, the request received by NextJS is the page request itself, which is your only chance to get the user's credentials.

You can get this data with `cookies()` or `headers()` functions:

```js
import { cookies, headers } from "next/headers";
export default async function Page() {
  headers().forEach((value, key) => console.log(`${key}:${value}`));
  console.log(cookies().toString());
}
```

## How to set the cookies?

Now we know how to get cookies on server, but the question is how do we set cookies for the client?

### 1. Just use cookies for authentication

If your external authentication app supports setting cookies, you can send login requests directly to the remote auth server from the client side (only for this request), and then have that auth server set cookies for the client. However, in this case you may need to be careful about cross-domain cookies.

### 2. Use server side function to wrap your authentication token

(You can certainly set the token as a cookie on client, but it's safer to set the http-only cookie on server.)

If you don't want the login request to be handled on client, or you just can't use cookies because the authentication app are returning a token, you can wrap that in a `server action` or `route handler`

By far the most elegant approach is to use a `server action`:

1. The client calls the `login()` server action through a form component with required data. (e.g. `username` and `password`)
2. In this server action, call `fetch("https://external.auth.server")` with required data.
3. Get user token from fetch `Response`.
4. Set the token as a http-only cookie for security shake.
5. Response to client with that `set-cookie`.

On subsequent requests on server, you can get this cookie containing auth token back. All you need to do is to attach it to your data `fetch()` (e.g. in the `Authorization` header)

Comment: I don't think this entirely answers the question. As I understand it, the situation to translate is where in the pages router you would be calling an api route of the same next server, and thus put auth on this api route, how do you get the same level of protection when replacing the api route fetch call (e.g. client-side post) with a direct serverside action using app router. How to make sure that the serverside action cannot be called by unauthorized user, e.g. by direct call to the server. The docs only explain how to protect the page itself from loading, not how to auth serverside action.

Comment: @MarkNelissen There are two ways to do authentication. The latter is used in the answer: 
1. Next.js as a full-stack framework. i.e. your authentication and even backend data is handled in Next.js. You can use `next-auth` to act as an auth server and authenticate the user in pages / server actions.
2. Next.js only as a front-end framework. You need to work with a secured backend API to query the data and authenticate users in the backend API. In this case, The purpose of server actions is just to wrap and forward cookies to the backend.

Comment: On the split between both, we agree, and also your solution works for the second one, as you indicate yourself. But my understanding of the initial question is that it is actually number 1, but with the caveat that auth is externalised and not using NextAuth.

Comment: @MarkNelissen The logic in my comment was a bit confusing. I've updated the answer with a clearer statement. Actually, in either case, whenever you use a third-party authentication server you need to `get` / `set` client cookies using the approach mentioned in the answer. The only difference between the two cases is that 1) you need to manually parse the cookie to token, and verify the user token in Next.js before fetching data; 2) you only need to forward the cookies to the back-end server.